# Is there any way to reduce the number of JS files included by rails-backbone(code brew)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

Trying out the [example usage of "codebrew rails-backbone](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails),
everything works fine but the amount of javascript files included is far too big.

All the models, routers, views, templates are loaded, which amounts to 15 javascript includes.

Is there any way to reduce this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to do this, it is done out of the box with rails. While your rails instance is in development mode, you get all separate javascript and css files. When you switch it to production, it's concatenated and minified into one file.

See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

You can see this for yourself by doing

```
set RAILS_ENV=production
rails s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can

1) concatenate the scripts

2) minify the resulting script using [google closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)

That's what I do in my "makefiles" (I use ant) when I have a lot of js scripts as the main latence in this kind of cases is usually due to the number of requests (the total size of the scripts is mostly irrelevant except in extreme cases).

Comment: Be careful to set the level of minification as some scripts don't support an important minification. You have to test it.